# Using directive - Find all methods and properties in use by reference

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019

Say in VS2019 I have a lengthy class with `using directives` as

```
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Threading;
```

Is there a way to find and list all of the methods/properties/objects etc that reference a highlighted reference?

For example, ideally I would like to highlight `System.Text` and provide a list of all lines that use this reference, eg a list of items such as `StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();`

A bit like `Find All` but finding items that require certain selected references.

Comment: Why? Do you want to remove unused usings? ReSharper and Visual Studio 2019 can help with that.

Comment: I need to refactor a project and there are lots of 3rd party classes that have very similar method names. System.Text was just an example, I'm more interested in locating code linked to a particular using directive.

Comment: @armagedescu - I did look at the object browser but it's not too helpful in this case as it's more useful for going down the dependency tree rather than up.

Comment: Simple.... Remove the using statement and voila! Everything that needs it becomes an error which you can easily navigate to.